# Get Content Type hub URL

Tags: content-type-hub

Is there a way(programmatically) to get the Content type hub URL?
Javascript? REST?
I'm referencing some files in the Content Type Hub in a custom forms, so everytime we deploy in a new server I have to change the files, I want to avoid that